# Using multiple params with React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
<Route path="/:user" component={Home}>
  <Route path="/:thing(/:version)" component={Thing}/>
</Route>
```

So, I've got two dynamic objects in my application that I'd like to be controlled by route params in react-router. Using the code above, both `/0` and `/0/3` take me to `Home`. I need `/0/3` to take me to `Thing`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here... Does react-router even support multiple dynamic params next to each other like this? I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens here is that you've given React Router two paths that can both match on `/anything`. By default then React Router matches the first one it can find.

To dig deeper, if I go to `/pudding`, React Router can't know if you meant `/:user` or `/:thing`. Since `/:user` occurs first, that option will be chosen.

You also need to make sure if nesting routes is what you want. Currently, your `Thing` route is nested below `Home`, which means that it is rendered via `this.props.children` in your `Home` component. So, for your current `Thing` route, `Home` will always be rendered too, with `Thing` as a child. If your `Home` component doesn't render `this.props.children`, `Thing` will not be shown.

I suspect you just want two different pages. What you could do to achieve that is the following:

```js
<Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/user/:user" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/:thing(/:version)" component={Thing}/>
</Router>
```

This will make every `/user/name` go to the `Home` component, and every other `/random` (with an optional extra level) will go to `Thing`. If you wonder why in this case React Router doesn't take `/user/name` to the `Thing` route, it's because it still matches in the order your routes are specified. Because your `Home` route matches the requested URL, no siblings of this route are tested anymore.